# Upload file images for products of shopping cart in Nodejs using API and convert them to base64

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to create a new product for shopping cart using API Nodejs with MySQL with realtionship as
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWrUj.png). A product have multiple images. So I want to create new products and its images by API. First, I have already created new products without images. 
Now I want to write API upload images with product. I don't know how to solve it.

This is my code to create a new product without images

```
module.exports.addMyProduct = (req, res, next)=>{
    var purchasePrice = req.body.purchasePrice;
    var discount = req.body.discount;
    var salePrice = (purchasePrice*(100-discount))/100;

    const newProduct = {
        subCategoriesid: req.body.subCategoriesid,
        usersid: req.user.id, 
        name: req.body.name,
        image: image,
        size: req.body.size,
        color: req.body.color,
        brand: req.body.brand,
        material: req.body.material,
        origin: req.body.origin,
        purchasePrice: purchasePrice,
        discount: discount,
        salePrice: salePrice,
        shortIntro: req.body.shortIntro,
        description: req.body.description,
        quantity: req.body.quantity,
        status: req.body.status,
        createdAt: req.body.createdAt,
        editedAt: req.body.editedAt
    }

    Products.create(newProduct)
    .then(newProduct=>{
        res.status(201).send({
            msg: 'Create product successfully',
            newProduct
        })
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.json('Cannot add new product:' +  err);
    })
}
```

**How to create a product with multiple images and convert them to base64?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use FormData to send Binary file within JSON data

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

OR

You can upload image at other API, then use the Url response from that API set to the Product.

Comment: Can you explain the second way in details?